# Varnish server in front of nginx server with multiple virtualhosts

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, django, varnish, gunicorn

I have tried to search for a solution for this, but can't find any documentation/tips on my specific setup.

My setup:

Backendserver: ngnix: 2 different websites (2 top domains) in virtualenv, running gunicorn/python/django
Backendserver hardware(VPS) 2gb ram, 8 CPU

Databaseserver: postgresql - pg_bouncer
Backendserver hardware (VPS) 1gb ram, 8 CPU

Varnishserver: only running varnish
Varnishserver hardware (VPS) 1gb ram, 8 CPU

I'm trying to set up a varnish server to handle rare spike in traffic (20 000 unique req/s) The spike happens when a tv program mention one of the sites.

What do I need to do, to make the varnish server cache both sites/domains on my backendserver?

My /etc/varnish/default.vcl :

```
backend django_backend {
    .host = "local.backendserver.com";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

My /usr/local/nginx/site-avaible/domain1.com

```
upstream gunicorn_domain1 {
    server unix:/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN1>/<APP1>/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;

}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 8080;
        server_name domain1.com;
        rewrite ^ http://www.domains.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 8080;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name  www.domain1.com;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    root /home/<USER>/<APP>-media/;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://gunicorn_domain1;
        break;
      }
    }

}
```

My /usr/local/nginx/site-avaible/domain2.com

```
upstream gunicorn_domain2 {
    server unix:/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN2>/<APP2>/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;

}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 8080;
        server_name domain2.com;
        rewrite ^ http://www.domains.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 8080;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name  www.domain2.com;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    root /home/<USER>/<APP>-media/;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://gunicorn_domain2;
        break;
      }
    }

}
```

Right now, If I try the Ip of the varnishserver I only get served domain1.com. Would everything be correct if I change the DNS of the two domain to point to the varnishserver, or is there extra setup before it would work?

Question 2: Do I need a dedicated server for varnish, or could I just install varnish on my backendserver, or would the server run out of memory quick?

Comment: Answer 1 - At the moment if you request via an IP you'll get the first site returned in the config.  To get the second domain you could switch their places in the config to test this. Answer 2 - Difficult to define need a dedicated server.  It'll certainly make sense in terms of planning future resilience (load balancing etc.) if you have separate servers.  Have you considered using NGINx as a front end proxy to Apache?  (How to and why: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-front-end-proxy-for-apache)

Comment: Why do you use varnish in front of nginx instead of nginx? Nginx has pretty rich caching feature set.

Comment: @VBart Good point... I evaluated Varnish but nginx's caching does all I need.

Comment: I have tested to change dns of two subdomains to the varnish server, and everything looks like its working. I'll look into caching just from nginx.

Comment: @Garreth00: check for [proxy_cache_*](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache)